# Filter a pandas DataFrame by a dict

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a DataFrame like this:

```
       Num1   Num2 
1       1      0
2       3      2
3       5      4
4       7      6
5       9      8
```

And I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {
    
    "Num1": 2,
    "Num2": 5
}
```

I want to return the values from the DataFrame from each column that matches the key and the values greater than or equal to the value in the key.

My result should look like this:

```
       Num1   Num2 
1       nan    nan
2       3      nan
3       5      nan
4       7      6
5       9      8
```

How might I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same idea of @db's answer using [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) instead of [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to keep the logic, i.e use [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) rather than [`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html):

```
>>> df.where(df >= d)  # or df.where(df.ge(d))
   Num1  Num2
0   NaN   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   5.0   NaN
3   7.0   6.0
4   9.0   8.0
```

**Edit**

To go further, if you want to use a different operator, you can change the input as follows:

```
filters = [  # col, op, val
    ('Num1', '>=', 2),
    ('Num2', '<', 5)
]

m = pd.concat([df.eval(f'{col} {op} {val}').rename(col)
               for col, op, val in filters], axis=1)
out = df.where(m)
print(out)

# Output
   Num1  Num2
0   NaN   0.0
1   3.0   2.0
2   5.0   4.0
3   7.0   NaN
4   9.0   NaN
```

Alternative:

```
filters = {
    'Num1': '>= 2',
    'Num2': '< 5'
}

m = pd.concat([df.eval(f'{col} {cond}').rename(col)
               for col, cond in filters.items()], axis=1)
out = df.where(m)
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Num1": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
                   "Num2": [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]})
print(df.mask(df.lt(d)))
#    Num1  Num2
# 0   NaN   NaN
# 1   3.0   NaN
# 2   5.0   NaN
# 3   7.0   6.0
# 4   9.0   8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Num1': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 'Num2': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]})

d = {'Num1': 2, 'Num2': 5}


print(df[df[d.keys()].gt(d)])
```

```
   Num1  Num2
0   NaN   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   5.0   NaN
3   7.0   6.0
4   9.0   8.0
```